# R: Why is the if-statement evaluated twice even if there is no loop?

Tags: r, if-statement

I know there are already a lot of questions about if-statements, but since they almost all contain loops, I haven't found a suitable answer yet.

I built a dataframe with the most important statistical values (p-values, Cohen's d,...) from 3 tests:

```
p1 = 0.9
p2 = 0.00021
p3 = 0.001
stat <- data.frame(ID=c("Group A","Group B","Group C"),pvalues = c(p1,p2,p3),cohensd=c(0.14,0.5,0.2))
```

Now, if at least two p-values are smaller than 0.05, I would like to output a message stating which group has the largest effect (based on Cohen's d) - but of course only if the p-value is smaller than 0.05 for this group.

In my case, the desired output would be "The effect is strongest for Group B."

I tried the following:

```
if(((p1 < 0.05)+(p2 < 0.05) + (p3 < 0.05))>=2 ){paste("The effect is strongest for", stat$ID[which.max(stat$cohensd)&stat$pvalues<0.05])}
```

But what I get is:
"The effect is strongest for Group B" "The effect is strongest for Group C"

Apparently, the if-statement is evaluated twice, but I can't figure out why. Can someone find my error? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat$ID[which.max(stat$cohensd)&stat$pvalues<0.05]` returns `"Group B" "Group C"` hence you get both the groups printed. You might use `stat$ID[which.max(stat$cohensd &stat$pvalues<0.05)]` which will give you only `"Group B"` but note that `which.max` would give you the first group if all the values are evaluated as `FALSE`. A better option would be to use `which(...)[1]` which will return `NA` if all the values are `FALSE`.

```
if(((p1 < 0.05)+(p2 < 0.05) + (p3 < 0.05))>=2 ){paste("The effect is strongest for", stat$ID[which(stat$cohensd &stat$pvalues<0.05)[1]])}

#[1] "The effect is strongest for Group B"
```